# Delete a nested array from firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

i have a nested array (arrays inside an array) of frame numbers in which each frame number has its own data.
I am not bothered about the frame number right now.

considering the array as `[[0-100][100-200][200-300][300-400][400-500]]` where `[0-100] [100-200]` is an array of frame numbers. If i want to delete the `[100-200]` array, what should I do?

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: I want you to try 2 things : 1. Use FieldValue.arrayRemove to remove an element from an array by value. The elements can be of Type (*) as mentioned [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayRemove). The value has to match the whole element in the array, and it will delete all elements in the array that match that value i.e. FieldValue.arrayRemove([100,....200]).  2) Use Array.splice. Iterate through each element in array(which is also an array) then array.splice(1,1) which means splicing the array at position 1 for [100-200] and delete count should be 1.

Comment: Posting the comments as answer as this question is upvoted 3 times and should have a proper answer. I think my answer is correct, so have put it as an answer for Community reach.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `FieldValue.arrayRemove` to remove an element from an array by
  value. The elements can be of Type (*) as mentioned [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayRemove). The
  value has to match the whole element in the array, and it will delete
  all elements in the array that match that value i.e.
  `FieldValue.arrayRemove([100,....200])`.
- Use `Array.splice`. Iterate through each element in array(which is also
  an array) then `array.splice(1,1)` which means splicing the array at
  position 1 for [100-200] and delete count should be 1